# mathematical transfer for different camera attributes

Tags: image-processing, opencv, image-registration

Suppose I have two camera shoots(Image1,Image2) for the exactly same scene (each pixel is alignment correctly) but from different cameras and different light conditions. I want to remove this light difference. I tried two way till now:

1. S,V component adjustment
2. Gamma correction

   I am getting result around 7/255 difference after adjustment.

I am looking for a mathematical transform "F", something like `Adjusted_Image=F(Image1)`  which leads to `|Image1-Image2| ~ 0`
The "F" function will contains must-tuned parameters (a,b,c,....).

Any ideas of the formula of "F"?

many thanks,

Comment: Hi This process is also known as Color Correction. You may find more info here.http://ia802707.us.archive.org/23/items/Lectures_on_Image_Processing/EECE253_05_ColorCorrection.pdf

Comment: The results are pretty good better than gamma or SV in most cases. I thank you @ Balaji R... you may please add it as answer so I can accept it. if not I gonna right it as answer. many thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Process is Known as Color Correction.It is Explained in more detail [here](http://ia802707.us.archive.org/23/items/Lectures_on_Image_Processing/EECE253_05_ColorCorrection.pdf).

To Give a short Explanation:

Lets suppose

You have a Input Color Matrix represented as

```
    | R_O1 G_O1 B_O1 |
A = | R_O2 G_O2 B_O2 |
    | R_On G_On B_On |
```

and a Reference Target Color Matrix represented as

```
    | R_T1 G_T1 B_T1 |
B = | R_T2 G_T2 B_T2 |
    | R_Tn G_Tn B_Tn |
```

Color Correction Matrix X is computed as follows:

```
            **A X = B** 

    | R_O1 G_O1 B_O1 |     | A11 A12 A13 |   =  | R_T1 G_T1 B_T1 |  
    | R_O2 G_O2 B_O2 |   * | A21 A22 A23 |      | R_T2 G_T2 B_T2 |
    | R_On G_On B_On |     | A31 A32 A33 |      | R_Tn G_Tn B_Tn |
```

**X = (B.A^T)(A.A^T)^-1**

Some one please help me editing the formulas!

Comment: Thanks again.. I have question please.. This process is somehow linear. Is there another non-linear way that let each channel depend on itself and the other two channels? many thansk

Comment: Actually i'm also working on similar problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29667226/how-to-linearise-an-input-image-before-applying-color-correction I think this may be the starting point http://www.littlecms.com/ & http://opencolorio.org/

Comment: Going to check them... hope you the best :)